# Как вывести построенный график в новом окне tkintera?

Tags: python, tkinter, вывод, график, окно

Есть код, который создает главное окно с кнопкой, которая открывает новое окно.

```
class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Вывести график", 
                                command=self.create_window)
        self.button.pack(padx = 20, pady = 20, fill="both")

    def create_window(self):
        self.counter += 1
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("Window #%s" % self.counter)
        l = tk.Label(t, text="This is window #%s" % self.counter)
        l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=100, pady=100)

    main = MainWindow(root)
    main.pack(padx = 20, pady = 20, fill="both", expand=True)
```

Отдельно есть другой код, который создает график переменной m и выводит его на страничку.

```
class GrapfPage3(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="График", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot(m)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

Только начал изучать tkinter и не могу сообразить, как правильно совместить эти две части, чтобы просчитанный график выводился в новом окне при нажатии на кнопку в первой части кода. Пробовал подставлять часть с figure и canvas, но результата не было. Подскажите пожалуйста, кто хорошо знаком с tkinter, как это правильно реализовать.

Comment: В методе `create_window` класса `MainWindow` создаете экземпляр объекта `GrapfPage3`, указав родительским объектом `t`, упаковываете.

Comment: @insolor Честно говоря не очень понятно что нужно сделать. Можете пожалуйста объяснить как совсем для новичка куда в create_window следует вставить экземпляр класса GraphPage3 и где указывать t, вместо parent??

Answer (score 2):

У вас класс `GrapfPage3` унаследован от `tk.Frame`, значит базовое поведение у него будет такое же как у `tk.Frame`, т.е., например, его можно разместить внутри окна `tk.TopLevel`:

```
def create_window(self):
    self.counter += 1
    t = tk.Toplevel(self)
    t.wm_title("Window #%s" % self.counter)
    l = tk.Label(t, text="This is window #%s" % self.counter)
    l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=100, pady=100)

    graph = GrapfPage3(t, None)  # родительский элемент (parent) - t
    # что подразумевается у вас под controller не понятно, поэтому передаю просто None
    graph.pack()
```